# CSS Button Issue

Tags: css, button

I'm a newbie to coding so I apologize if this is something obvious. I used a CSS button creator to generate this code and it does nothing. Atom is showing an error relating to CSS webkits. 
Error reads: 
"Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome)."

I thought this might be something I need to install on my browser but I'm not sure.
Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can learn about this and fix the issue?

[Button Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZQN.png)

Comment: You don't need any of those vendor prefixes. CSS gradients, box shadows, and border radii are all supported by modern browsers. The old gradient syntax used by a 10 year old browser is long since deprecated.

Comment: DO NOT post or link images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find your answer here: [css lint gradient definitions](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Require-all-gradient-definitions)

As the error states you are missing the linear gradient for Safari 4+ and Chrome (aka "Old WebKit"): `-webkit-gradient`